# how to connect SQL and R.Net?

Tags: sql, r, connection

I want to connect SQL database from R.Net. I am using R.Net from vb.net.
Is it possible? If it possible how?

Using vb.net i have added some .DLL  file (R.Net.dll,RdotNET.dll) which will help to work R.Net and i did some coding to find sum.

code:

```
Imports RdotNET

Public Class Form1

    Dim engine As REngine
    Dim sum As Double

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)   Handles MyBase.Load

        REngine.SetDllDirectory("@C:\Program Files\R\R-2.12.0\bin\i386")
        engine = REngine.CreateInstance("RDotNet")
        engine.EagerEvaluate("sum<- 5 + 6")
        sum = engine.GetSymbol("sum").AsNumeric.First()
        MessageBox.Show(sum.ToString)

    End Sub
```

now i need to connect to Sql. i need to read a table data and display it in a my app

sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing R code that uses R.NET to call a .NET connection to a SQL database seems like an overcomplicated way of doing things.  Unless your use case demands this (edit your question to explain what you are doing), I recommend using one of the many R packages that connect directly to SQL databases.  Take a look at `dbConnect`, `RMySQL`, `RPostgreSQL`, `RODBC`, `RSQLite` or `RpgSQL`, depending upon what sort of database it is.